# CSP style asynchronous programming in Scheme (CHICKEN)

Tags: asynchronous, scheme, lisp, chicken-scheme

Is there an egg or some library that would allow me to write CSP style programs in Scheme? By CSP style I mean what's implemented in Go (go/channel/select) or Clojure's core.async.

Comment: I don't know what Chicken offers, but Racket has [place channels](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/parallelism.html#%28part._effective-places%29).

Answer (score 2):

[Chicken Scheme](http://call-cc.org/) has a [channel](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/channel) egg that you could try out.

```
$ chicken-install -s channel
```

Answer (score 2):

[Chicken](http://call-cc.org) now also has a [gochan](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/gochan) egg (which I wrote). It's much simpler than [channel](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/channel), but [channel](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/channel) seems to be a little complex and I'm unsure of how well it has been tested.

```
$ chicken-install -s gochan
$ csi -R gochan -p '(gochan-receive (gochan "hello world"))'
hello world
```